# Try catch does not work in Azure server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, try-catch

In the config of my application I deleted the customErrors to make a test of an error that is difficult to replicate.

And where the error should be happening I put a try:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TarefaHoras.Add(tarefaHora);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException ex)
            {
                ErroDetalhe erro = new ErroDetalhe();
                erro.Data = tarefaHora.Data;
                erro.UsuarioId = tarefaHora.ApplicationUserId;
                erro.JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tarefaHora);
                erro.Tipo = "TarefaHora";
                erro.Controller = "TarefaHoras";
                erro.Action = "Create Post";
                erro.Exception = ex.GetType().FullName;

                db.ErroDetalhes.Add(erro);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("ErroNaAtualizacaoDaBase", "Erros", new { id = erro.ID });                        
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View(tarefaHora);
    }
```

This error only happens at runtime and only on Azure server, so my attempt was to get a better description of the error and for this I created a table where the information is deposited.

But....

The problem is that the View error that I'm getting is not the View "ErrorInputUpdate" that I created and that is redirected in Catch.

I am getting the default AspNET error view.

So I went into Shared Views and deleted the default page and removed customErrors from web.config.

And even then Azure still brings the default error view.

Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Build and publish in **Debug**, not Release if you want to have the same error handling experience you have in Visual Studio.

Comment: How did you recommend I published in Debug, but I received an so generic error [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] Doesnt show nothing more. Any idea?

Comment: Add a breakpoint and step through. You can do it remotely - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio (Remote Debugging section). The stack trace should already give you enough context to understand WHERE things are breaking.

Answer (score 0):

So calling `db.SaveChanges();` generates an exception. That means that the context `db` is invalid and it should be resolved or discarded.

However, what you are doing is creating an error entry and add using the same `db` context which is still in a faulty state. So the call to `db.SaveChanges();` in your catch block will still generate an exception, but this time it won't be catched.

The solution is either to write the error to something else than the database, like a file or whatever or to use another EF context instance. Other options are to removed or correct the invalid entries before calling `db.SaveChanges();` again or do not store the error in the database but include all the details in the redirect view.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to separate all db.savechanges